# Showing that $\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+b}\rfloor=n \iff 0 \le b < 2n+1$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm reading Paul Zeitz's book on problem solving and he has a problem where we need to consider $g(m)= \lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor$. We then need to figure out for what $b \in \Bbb R$ it holds that $$g(n^2+b)=n.$$

He then states that this holds when $0\le b < 2n+1$, but I cannot figure out how to prove this. How can I show that $$\lfloor \sqrt{n^2+b}\rfloor=n \iff 0 \le b < 2n+1?$$

Comment: Well, what is $n^2+2n+1$?

Comment: It is $(n+1)^2$ @AndrewChin

Comment: I believe you mean for any nonnegative real numbers $b$ instead of $b\in\mathbb{R}$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
0\leq b<2n+1 &\iff n^2 \leq n^2+b <n^2+2n+1\\
&\iff n^2\leq n^2+b <(n+1)^2 \\
&\iff n\leq \sqrt{n^2+b} <n+1 \\
&\iff \lfloor\sqrt{n^2+b} \rfloor = n \\
\end{align}